# issue executing SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run the following query :

```
SELECT  
  A.STEPNAME, 
  A.BRDATE BRDATE_A, 
  B.BRDATE BRDATE_B, 
  MIN(A.STARTTIME) STARTTIME_A, 
  MAX(A.ENDTIME) ENDTIME_A, 
  MIN(B.STARTTIME) STARTTIME_B, 
  MAX(B.ENDTIME) ENDTIME_B, 
  'RUNTIME_A' = convert(VARCHAR,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,A.STARTTIME,A.ENDTIME),108) ,
  'RUNTIME_B' = convert(VARCHAR,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,B.STARTTIME,B.ENDTIME),108) 
FROM 
  CB_OPX_AUDIT_HIST A, 
  CB_OPX_AUDIT_HIST B
WHERE  
  A.BRDATE = ('05/11/2012') 
AND 
  B.BRDATE = ('05/16/2012') 
AND 
  A.BR = '03'
AND 
  A.STEPNAME=B.STEPNAME
AND 
  A.BR=B.BR
GROUP BY 
  A.STEPNAME, 
  A.ENDTIME, 
  A.STARTTIME,
  A.BRDATE,
  B.BRDATE,
  B.ENDTIME, 
  B.STARTTIME
ORDER BY  
  A.STARTTIME
```

I need the difference between 'RUNTIME_A'  AND  'RUNTIME_B' ..

Can someone tell me how do i get the difference in the above query.?

Comment: What datatype are `STARTTIME_A` and `ENDTIME` ?? I hope those are `DATETIME`! Then you definitely don't need to convert those to `VARCHAR` first - just do `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` on those dates and you're done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, I would suggest just changing from using VARCHAR to using DATETIME and run a simple datediff again

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
    convert(DATETIME,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,A.STARTTIME,A.ENDTIME),108), 
    convert(DATETIME,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,B.STARTTIME,B.ENDTIME),108)
)
```

You can wrap your original query as a subquery to simplify things.

Comment: If the difference between `A.STARTTIME` and `A.ENDTIME` is 10 minutes, your COVERT will yield `1900-01-11`, not `1900-01-01 00:10`.  This is because it will implicitly cast the `10` to a DATETIME, and treat it as a value in days, not minutes.  *[If the only desire is to have the difference in minutes, and both DATEDIFFs yield minutes, why not just subtract one DATEDIFF result from the other?]*

Comment: Yes, and both will be cast to 1900-01-01, so it will still work. It really depends on what the OP really needs

Comment: I mean; don't turn them into dates at all... You already have `a.start is X minutes from a.end` and `b.start is Y minutes from b.end`. So why not just do `X - Y`? What is the purpose of converting `X` to a date, and `Y` to a date, and then doing `DATEDIFF(minute, X_as_a_date, Y_as_a_date)`?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your whole query within another `SELECT` statement. And in the outer select statement you can simply select `RUNTIME_A - RUNTIME_B`.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean "get the difference"?

You already get the difference in minutes, will it always be less than one day?

How does this work for you?

```
DATEADD(
  minute,
  DATEDIFF(minute, A.STARTTIME, A.ENDTIME)
  -
  DATEDIFF(minute, B.STARTTIME, B.ENDTIME),
  0
)
```

Or...

```
CONVERT(
  VARCHAR(8),
  DATEADD(
    minute,
    DATEDIFF(minute, A.STARTTIME, A.ENDTIME)
    -
    DATEDIFF(minute, B.STARTTIME, B.ENDTIME),
    0
  ),
  108
)
```